# Access arguments of an... argument

Tags: javascript

Newbie question.  Consider

```
var foo = function(func) {
console.log(func.arguments);
}
```

The "foo" function takes one argument, which is a function.  How do I access the arguments that are passed along with the "func" function at runtime?

EDIT: I don't want to dynamically set the arguments to func, I want to find out what arguments are passed in with func so that  I can do something else with them.  Basically I want to store the argument passed in to func as a key and the result of that func as a value and store them in a hash object...  the ultimate goal will be to memoize various results of running "func" depending on what arguments are passed in.  For now though my curiosity is piqued about how to access / store those arguments.

Comment: Are you trying to access, say, `arg` in `func(arg)` from the `foo` scope? Are you imagining calling `foo(func(arg))`?

Comment: I think you are confusing the function - func - and the execution of the function - func(arguments). In your example you are passing the function and it has no argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access them at runtime of `foo` as when `foo` runs `func` has never been called.

```
foo(function(){
    console.log('This is never executed');
});
```

If you do execute `func` within `foo` then you must have access to the arguments at that time:

```
var foo = function(func) {
    func(1, 2, 3); // Now func is called, and you know what the arguments are
}
```

Comment: if I were to do 
    var foo = function(func) {
        var blah = func.apply(this, arguments)
    }
could I then access the arguments of blah?

Comment: @ggg The arguments of `blah` would just be the values in the array-like `arguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a function as your argument, the function has no arguments passed in with it.  You are passing a reference to the function which would have to get called inside of the function then you would have arguments.

You could almost say that the arguments of `func` is `undefined` as you haven't called the function yet.  And from the scope of `foo`, you would be able to set the arguments to be what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
var foo = function(func) {
    return func.args;
},
bar = function(){
    bar.args = arguments;
};
bar('a','b');
foo(bar); // Arguments object ['a','b']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//     var
//         base_fn    = function(){}, 
//         tracer_fn  = tracer( base_fn );
//
function tracer( fn ) { 

   return ( function( argsCache, F, _s ){ 


               // define new fn that will have that capability
               // it's a wrapper for original fn

               var
                   fn2    = function(/*...params*/) {

                              var

                                // temporary stores original fn's result
                                out, 

                                // capture passed arguments
                                theArgs = _s.call( arguments ), 


                                //
                                //  you can implement 'memo' functionality here
                                //  if that's your goal, 
                                //  by 'scaning' already processed inputs
                                //  in argsCache array
                                //  and optionaly runing original fn, 
                                //  if no match is found
                                //

                                // save input and output of fn as h-map
                                argsIO  = {
                                            input  : theArgs, 
                                            output : null
                                          };

                                // execute original fn 
                                // pass it captured arguments
                                // 'remember' it's result
                                out = F.apply( this, theArgs );

                                // save calculated value
                                argsIO.output = out;

                                // 'push' fn input-output record on the cache
                                argsCache.push( argsIO );

                                // return whatever original fn returned
                                return out;

                            };

                  // provide 'static' access to 'closured' cache
                  // use the array to inspect 'arguments history'
                  fn2.args = argsCache;

                  // provide a way to empty cache
                  fn2.clear = function () { 
                      fn2.args.splice( 0, fn2.args.length );
                      return fn2.args;
                  };

                  // return fn 'upgrade'
                  return fn2;

   } )( [], fn, Array.prototype.slice );

}


function basefn() {

   // doStuff( arguments );
   // returning value, as well as arguments, 
   // are recorded by tracer fn

   return arguments.length;
}


// get the 'tracer' fn
var
   fn = tracer( basefn );



// run it couple of times 
// passing arbitrary arguments
fn( 12345, new XMLHttpRequest() );
fn('a', 'z', /^[a-z]+$/ );
fn( {}, [1,2,3] );
fn( location, document );
fn( Math );

//
// access 'args history' through fn.args ( array ) property
//
//   var
//       lastCallIO = fn.args[ fn.args.length - 1 ];
//

console.log( fn.args );

//
// empty cache, free some memory
//
//   fn.clear();
//
//
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the arguments of func when it's called, but you can return a new function that wraps func and does any additional processing when that function is called. Local variables in foo are shared between all calls of the function returned so can be used to implement memoization.

```
var foo = function(func) {
    return function() {
        // Get arguments from func.
        console.log("Calling func", arguments);
        // Call func with arguments.
        return func.apply(null, arguments);
    };
};

var bar = function(x) {
    return x * 2;
};

var foobar = foo(bar);

console.log(foobar(10));
console.log(foo(bar)(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// Function.memo
//
;
( function ( _host_ ) {

    var
        t    = !0,
        f    = !t,
        pn   = String( this ),
        mmfn = function ( fn, mem_read_callback, mem_write_callback ) {

            return ( function( input, output, mrcb, mwcb, k, v ) {

                    // capture original fns
                    var
                        origFn = this,

                        // define 'memo' fn
                        mmfn   = function ( /*...params*/ ) {

                            // capture passed arguments
                            var inputArgs = slc( arguments );

                            // reset the flag,
                            // -1 indicates that passed arguments haven't been proccessed yet.
                            k = -1;

                            // see if args have been already processed
                            // scan inputs[]
                            each( input, function ( input_args, pos ) {
                                // update k to point to memoized args
                                return ( is_same_arrays( inputArgs, input_args ) ) ? ( k = pos, f ) : t;
                            } );

                        // if k is -1 passed args are processe for the 1st time
                        //   execute original fn,
                        //   store result in output[],
                        //   store arguments[] in inputs[],
                        //   call provided ( optional ) 'mem_write_callback',
                        //   return result
                        // else
                        // call provided ( optional )'mem_read_callback',
                        // return memoized result
                        return  ( k == -1 ) ?
                                (
                                    v = origFn.apply( this, inputArgs ),
                                    input.push( inputArgs ),
                                    output.push( v ),
                                    ( isfn( mwcb ) && mwcb.call( this, inputArgs, v ) ),
                                    v
                                ):
                                ( isfn( mrcb ) && mrcb.call( this, inputArgs, output[k] ), output[k] );

                    };

                // optionaly provide access to cache
                mmfn.cache = {
                                inputs  : input,
                                outputs : output
                             };

                mmfn.mclear = function () {
                    input.splice(  0, input.length  );
                    output.splice( 0, output.length );
                };

                // return memoizer
                return mmfn;

            } ).call( fn, [], [], mem_read_callback, mem_write_callback );
        };





    // #helpers
    function is_same_arrays( a1, a2 ) {
        var flg = t;
        return ( each( a1, function ( v, k ) { return ( v === a2[k] ) ? t: ( flg = f ) ; } ), flg );
    }
    function each( arr, fn ) {
        for ( var l = arr.length, i = 0; i < l; i++ )
            if ( ( fn.call( arr, arr[i], i ) ) === f ) break;
        return arr;
    }
    function slc( args, i, j ) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call( args, i, j );
    }
    function isfn( fn ) {
        return typeof fn === 'function';
    }



    // attach 'memo' fn to host obj
    _host_[pn] = mmfn;

} ).call( new String('memo'),  ( typeof context === 'undefined' ? Function : context ) );



var
f1 = Function.memo(
                    function ( v ) { return v*v; },
                    function ( inpArr, res ) { console.log('cache read: ', inpArr.join(''),', ', res);  },
                    function ( inpArr, res ) { console.log('cache write: ', inpArr.join(''),', ', res);  }
                );

f1(1);
f1(2);
f1(1);
f1(2);
f1(1);
f1(3);
//
// logs
//
// cache write, 1 , 1
// cache write, 2 , 4
// cache read, 1 , 1
// cache read, 2 , 4
// cache read, 1 , 1
// cache write, 3 , 9
//
```